# Getting 'too many parameters passed' to stored procedure on ASPX page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, parameters, sqldatasource

I'm having trouble figuring this error out. I have a grid on an ASPX page that displays data from a stored procedure in an SQL Server 2008 database. When the page loads, I get the following error:

```
"Procedure or function <sp_name> has too many arguments specified."
```

Here is the code for the grid and the datasource:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ShowFooter="True" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
        AllowSorting="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MerchantID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"
                SortExpression="MerchantID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MerchantName" HeaderText="Merchant" SortExpression="MerchantName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RapidTuitionID" HeaderText="RapidTuition ID" SortExpression="RapidTuitionID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateCreated" HeaderText="Enrolled" SortExpression="DateCreated" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Commands">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="ImpersonateUserLinkButton" runat="server" OnClick="Command_Click"
                        CommandName="impersonate" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MerchantID") %>' CssClass="table_command">Impersonate</asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            No data to display.
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <PagerStyle CssClass="pager" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Development %>"
        SelectCommand="sp_GatewayMerchants" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="PromotionPlaceHolderTop$StartDate" Name="StartDate"
                DefaultValue="1/1/2010" PropertyName="Text" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="PromotionPlaceHolderTop$EndDate" Name="EndDate"
                DefaultValue="12/31/2010" PropertyName="Text" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="PromotionPlaceHolderTop$StatusActive" DefaultValue="true"
                Name="StatusActive" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="PromotionPlaceHolderTop$StatusDeactive" DefaultValue="true"
                Name="StatusDeactive" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Boolean" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here's the code from the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GatewayMerchants] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @StartDate DateTime, 
    @EndDate DateTime,
    @StatusActive bit,
    @StatusDeactive bit
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT 
        m.MerchantID AS [ID],
        m.MerchantName,
        CASE m.StatusFlag WHEN 1 THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Deactive' END AS [Status],
        m.RapidTuitionID,
        m.DateCreated
    FROM
        Merchant m
    WHERE
        (CONVERT(varchar,m.DateCreated,112) BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(DATETIME,@StartDate,101),112) AND CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(DATETIME,@EndDate,101),112))
        AND
        (
            (@StatusActive = 1 AND m.StatusFlag = 1)
            OR 
            (@StatusDeactive = 1 AND m.StatusFlag = 0)
        )
    ORDER BY
        m.MerchantName
END
```

The datasource is passing 4 parameters, and the stored procedure is accepting 4, but when the page displays I get the error mentioned above. Am I missing something here?

**EDIT:** Here's the code behind for the template column. But I'm not sure how this could be causing extra parameters to the SP.

```
        protected void Command_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var merchantID = Convert.ToInt32(((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument);

        switch (((LinkButton)sender).CommandName)
        {
            case "impersonate":
                var gs = GatewaySession.Parse(Page.User.Identity.Name);
                gs.Role = GatewaySession.RoleEnum.Merchant;
                gs.MerchantID = merchantID;
                gs.CustomerID = -1;

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(gs.ToString(), false);

                Page.Session["MerchantID"] = gs.MerchantID;

                Response.Redirect("/Merchant/Default.aspx");
                break;
        }
    }
```

If I remove the ASP:LINKBUTTON the code works. So why would a LINKBUTTON be causing this?

Answer (score 4):

Use Profiler and check what parameters are really passed to SP.

Comment: Assuming he has privileges to run Profiler against his database =)

Answer (score 2):

From your code it looks like you're passing 4 parameters, but let's make sure that's what's happening during design AND run time.

### Design Time

In the Design view of your page, select your GridView and expand the extended menu by clicking the [>] and choose to refresh the schema. This may clear your item templates but that should be ok since you have your code saved elsewhere (i.e. here).

### Run Time

Hook onto the SqlDataSource.Selecting event and check your command parameters in debug mode.

ASPX

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Development %>"
    SelectCommand="sp_GatewayMerchants" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    OnSelecting=SqlDataSource1_Selecting>
    ...
```

CS

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e) {
    // check e.Command.Parameters
}
```

**EDIT**

Another thing you can try is set the DataKeyNames property of the Data

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ShowFooter="True" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
    AllowSorting="True" DataKeyNames="MerchantID">
```

**EDIT 2**

More things to try:

1. When you're "refreshing" your page,
   make sure to not use F5 or hit the
   Refresh button. Go to your browser's
   address field and hit Enter as to
   not have IsPostBack = true
2. Remove OnClick, CommandName, and
   CommandArguemnt from the
   LinkButton's declaration

Comment: I tried the suggestion above. Refreshing the Schema makes the error go away, of course I lose my column definitions, but the grid displays without error. I tried logging the "Selecting" as you suggest, but that method never gets called when the page loads. Are you sure that method works with stored procedures too?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it works for a stored procedure. Did you hook onto the Selecting event as shown above? ASPX: OnSelecting=SqlDataSource1_Selecting

Comment: As soon as I add the 'Template' column back, I get the error. Why would adding a template column cause more parameters to be passed to the SP? I have never seen this before.

Comment: I did hook into the event as above. Like this: OnSelecting="GatewayMerchantDataSource_Selecting", and I put a Log4Net Info log message in the method.

Comment: Ok, did you insert a break point in GatewayMerchantDataSource (assuming its scope is at least protected and not private)? Also, can you post your method that is handling the row command "impersonate"?

Comment: I can't set a break point. I can only use Log4Net messages to a log file on the server. The method is declared protected.

Comment: Are you deploying this solution to a remote server? If so, you can try to DEBUG > Attach to Process, then specify the remote server in the Qualifier field. This will only work if the remote server has MSVSMON.EXE running on it though. In any case, I've tried what I've posted and it does indeed work. I also notice that you're handling the RowBound event. Can you post GridView1_RowDataBound as well?

Comment: Yes, this is deployed to a server. I'll need to install the Remote Debugging Package, so I'll have to get ahold of an admin to do it. The Row bound event has one var to count the rows (ItemCount++).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use Visual Studio's local debug mode to launch an ASP.NET Development Server?

Comment: Update the solution with even more things to try.

Comment: Still trying to figure this one out. The admin is having trouble getting remote debugging working, so I can't step it. Will try your suggestions this morning.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `SQLDataSource.Selecting` event handler and check what parameters are passed to the stored procedure. The parameters can be found in `SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs.Arguments`.

The GridView might be passing unexpected parameters to the SP.

Answer (score 0):

It is security related, your web.config must indicate a different connection string setup (digest authentication or user login) 
while your stored procedure requires either one of them
check your stored procedure security.

Comment: I highly doubt it's a security related issue. He would get an entirely different error message involving authorization.