# Stored Procedure has too many parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, stored-procedures

---

> Posibale Duplicate [Getting 'too many parameters passed' to stored
>   procedure on ASPX page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314676/getting-too-many-parameters-passed-to-stored-procedure-on-aspx-page)

---

I'm using a SqlDataSource control for some update and delete functionality within a GridView.  I keep getting the runtime error `Procedure or function spUpdateTest has too many arguments specified.`  When I run the stored procedure in SQL Server it works fine.  When I click on the delete portion of the GridView, that works.  However, when I try to update I get the above error.

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbcsDrugCards %>" 
            DeleteCommand="spDeleteTest" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
            InsertCommand="spInsertTest" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
            SelectCommand="spGetAllTest" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
            UpdateCommand="spUpdateTest" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="PatientId" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="PatientId" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="RaceId" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CountyId" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DateOfBirth" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="SesId" Type="Int32" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="PatientId" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="RaceId" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CountyId" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DateOfBirth" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="SesId" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

You can see the six parameters in the SqlDataSource.  Now here is my stored procedure

```
create proc spUpdateTest  
 @PatientId int  
,@RaceId int  
,@CountyId int  
,@Gender varchar(50)  
,@DateOfBirth date  
,@SesId int  
as  
begin  
update t  
set  t.raceid = @RaceId  
 ,t.countyId = @CountyId  
 ,t.gender = @Gender  
 ,t.DateOfBirth = @DateOfBirth  
 ,t.SocioEconomicStatusId = @SesId  
from test as t  
where t.patientId = @PatientId  
end
```

both have six parameters. GridView for good measure in case it makes a difference

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="patientId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="patientId" HeaderText="patientId" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="patientId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RaceId" HeaderText="RaceId" 
                    SortExpression="RaceId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CountyId" HeaderText="CountyId" 
                    SortExpression="CountyId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" 
                    SortExpression="Gender" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateOfBirth" HeaderText="DateOfBirth" 
                    SortExpression="DateOfBirth" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SocioEconomicStatusId" 
                    HeaderText="SocioEconomicStatusId" SortExpression="SocioEconomicStatusId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateEnrolled" HeaderText="DateEnrolled"  ReadOnly="true"
                    SortExpression="DateEnrolled" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

I don't know if it means anything, but I do have one field, `DateEnrolled` which is not meant to be edited by the user and is saved to the database as `GetDate()` whenever a `Test` object is added to the database.

C#

```
public static void UpdateTest(int PatientId, int raceID, int countyId, string gender
            , DateTime dateOfBirth, int sesId)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(TestDataAccessLayer.ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spUpdateTest", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RaceDescription", raceID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountyName", countyId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", gender);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", dateOfBirth);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SesDescription", sesId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientId", PatientId);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

this works

```
public static void DeleteTest(int PatientId)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(TestDataAccessLayer.ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spDeleteTest", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientId", PatientId);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

Where is this mysterious extra parameter coming from that I don't know about?

Comment: And for the future, use Profiler to find the exact code that is being sent. Usually once you see exactly what is sent, you can figure out what the problem is. This SQl Server specific but other databases have some sort of profiling capability that comes with them or you can get. Never write code against a database without a piece of software that lets you profile what is being actually sent to the db by the application. It will save you thousands of debugging hours.

Comment: @HLGEM that's the type of advice that I'm looking for: practical.

Answer (score 2):

Your parameter names in your C# code do not match what is defined in the stored procedure.

Here are the names that do not match what is in the stored procedure:

- @RaceId - it is `@RaceDescription` in the C# code
- @CountyId - it is `@CountryName` in the C# code
- @SesId - it is `@SesDescription` in the C# code

My guess, without seeing the code, for your delete stored procedure, is that the `@PatientId` parameters matches on both sides (C# and stored procedure) so that is why that one works and the update does not.

Comment: The problem that that everything in the GridView control was a bound field and thus was turned into a parameter for the stored procedure.  I had one field which was `GetDate()` which wasn't used.  So I added the extra parameter into the stored procedure with a default value of null and it worked as expected.